# HTTP GET request via fsockopen() returning extraneous characters

Tags: php, fsockopen

I'm using `fsockopen()` to request a value from a page on another server. The value returned is just a single word (ex. "French").  This works fine when I test on localhost (MAMP), making the request to the remote server.  However when I test server-to-server I end up with extra characters, such as:

`6%0D%0AFrench%0D%0A0%0D%0A%0D%0A`
or
`7%0D%0AEnglish%0D%0A0%0D%0A%0D%0A`

I'm using the http_request() function that's shown [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php#101872).  The only change I made was to increase the timeout.  I'm calling it using:

`$thelanguage = http_request('GET', $domain, 80, $path);`

I've tested this to and from multiple servers, and the extra characters show up when I make the request **from** anywhere except localhost.

I'm kind of at a loss as to how to proceed.  It appears that the 6 or 7 at the beginning of the strings returned are a character count, but I have no idea where that's coming from.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know it is flaky, but would you consider stripping this extraneous data?

Comment: I'll consider that a last resort. Since the extra data appears to change slightly based on the word returned, it wouldn't exactly be bulletproof. Also I don't know all the words that will eventually be returned, so I can't test all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It appears that the 6 or 7 at the beginning of the strings returned are a character count,

Yup!  You're seeing [chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding): data length, CRLF, the data, then two more CRLF pairs.  I believe that last CRLF means that it was the last chunk.

You probably want to use a more well-developed, well-tested, full-featured HTTP request mechanism, like the usually-built-in [curl extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or [PEAR's HTTP_Request2](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2).

Comment: I'd like to (originally done using cURL), but this script will be distributed to customers to run on their servers, which I don't have any control over.  I'm concerned that cURL or PEAR won't be installed/enabled in some cases, so I'm trying to use the lowest common denominator.

Comment: @dosboy, HTTP_Request2 is released under the BSD license, so you can simply bundle it (and the required Net_URL2) with your code.  It includes [adapters for both raw sockets and curl](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-request2.adapters.php), so it *should* work pretty well just about anywhere.

Comment: I'll investigate HTTP_Request2. In the meantime though you put me on the right track. I just added a `Content-Length` header to the responding page and no more chunking! Thanks!